# Behavior of a peculiar sequence at infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a question about the behavior of a peculiar function.
I'm solving a problem asking whether or not $\{n^2sin(\frac{3}{n^2}\}$ diverges or converges.

So I set up the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^2sin(\frac{3}{n^2})}$$

My initial belief is that because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n^2} = 0$, that we would have something like $${\infty * sin(0)}$$

Which would result in zero, but this answer was not correct. I decided to look at the behavior of the function of desmos so I could understand what's at play here. The result is a really interesting looking function!

[image: A very peculiar function]
It appears the limit of this function is 3. This is because of the vertical stretch of 3 on $sin$ I presume, but I don't understand quite why it is equal to 3. I become even more confused when I look at the function $sin(\frac{3}{n^2})$

[image: Another interesting function]
This function follows my original belief that such a function would go to zero! how is the multiplication of $n^2$ causing such a behavior? I have some guesses but I'd like to understand fully. Thanks for any comment/answer!

Comment: Hint: divide by and multiply by $3/n^2$. Then use the limit of $\sin y / y$ as $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1\to \sin t\approx t \text{ as } t\to 0$$
therefore in the limit you are dealing with
$\dfrac{3}{n^2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and so

$$\sin \frac{3}{n^2}\approx \frac{3}{n^2}$$
and finally as $n\to \infty$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \sin \frac{3}{n^2} =\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2  \frac{3}{n^2}=3$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), scaled by $n^2$...
As noted you want $n\to 0$...